# how can I change a single page url using htaccess in Localhost?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have to change a page url to another url. I am testing it in localhost.

i have a page url `http://localhost/casanainternational.com/trunk/php/test.php` .i want to access test.php page when i am typing `http://localhost/casanainternational.com/trunk/php/payment-failure`.

Here is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3&id=$4&status=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Are you using Joomla?

Comment: @Gunaseelan no core php

Comment: @Gunaseelan  i had put the code in localhosthost as  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/test/test.php $ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http:///test/payment-failure.$1 [R=301,L] ..But not working

Comment: @Gunaseelan yes but not working

Comment: Are you working in localhost?

Comment: @Gunaseelan yes i am checking it in the localhost.

Comment: have you made sure to enable "mod_rewrite" and restarted your apache ?

Comment: Where is your htaccess file? in `root` or `casanainternational.com` folder

Comment: @Lepanto in var/html/casanainternational.com/trunk/php

Comment: The code that is now in htaccess file, you wrote them? Because they, themselves serve as a redirect rule and anything of the format `some_url_file.html` and other formats mentioned in the code will be redirected to `index.php`

Answer (score 0):

The below code will fix your issue

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost/casanainternational.com/trunk/php/test.php $ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://localhost/casanainternational.com/trunk/php/payment-failure.$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^payment-failure/?$ test.php [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3&id=$4&status=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*)\.html$ index.php?module=$1&page=$2&action=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article on this, go to: How To Create Clean SEO Friendly URL

http://askguyson.com/how-to-create-clean-seo-friendly-url/

Comment: you should add `RewriteBase /` to your tutorial. For example if you use dynamic virtual hosts, you'll get a server error without `RewriteBase`

Comment: How can it possible to rewrite a url beautification for a single page ?